# Comparing array rows

Tags: r

I want to compare the first row of an array with the rest of them.
So I am running the following code but the results are not as expected.
For example flag[2, 1] is FALSE instead of TRUE (2 > 1).
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

```
yy <- array(data = c(1:16), dim = c(4,4))
yy
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16

flag <- (yy >= yy[1, ])
flag
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R stores arrays in columns, not in rows.  You want:

```
t(t(yy) >= yy[1,])
```

Another approach is:

```
yy >= matrix(yy[1,], nrow(yy), ncol(yy), byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that. Thank you a lot.